# How to get file location as variable in NWJS

Tags: javascript, nw.js

I am trying to get a file location as a variable in NW.JS. I have this code from the nw.js docs but can not figure out how to use it to return a file location. Do I need to write a script to use the id “fileDialog” to get the result? 
https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/file-dialogs

```
**HTML**
<input style="display:none;" id="fileDialog" type="file" />

**Javascript**
<script>
  function chooseFile(name) {
    var chooser = document.querySelector(name);
    chooser.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
      console.log(this.value);
    }, false);

    chooser.click();  
  }
  chooseFile('#fileDialog');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You better access the file name via the file list `input.files`:

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/file-dialogs look an the lile list section.

The called function is a async callback so you wont be able to return the names to the calling function. Just handle all files in the callback.

```
function chooseFile(name, handleFile) {
    var chooser = document.querySelector(name);
    chooser.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
        for(var f of this.files){
            console.log(f.name);
            console.log(f.path);
            handleFile(f.name, f.path);
        }
    }, false);

    chooser.click();  
}
chooseFile('#fileDialog', function(name, path){ ... /* do something with the file(s) */ });
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!